# check which user session is expired asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

To check session Expiry. I'm using following code in `Global.asax.cs`

```
void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs E)
{
    //get userId of the user whose session is expired!
}
```

Is there any way to check which user session is expired?

Comment: This would help you to do this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107196/access-membership-user-on-session-end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session_End is called when the session ends - X no. of minutes after last request.

```
private void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //This will run only when sessionstate mode is "InProc"    

    var Name= Session["UserName"];
    var Id= Session.SessionID;
}
```

Comment: Plagiarized from the duplicate!